# Transforming streaming data into a json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I have a streaming data coming from a source and I was able to capture few important variables like ID, Timestamp and Vital signs. What I am trying to do is create a json file object and unload it into a file system. This is one of the examples:

```
for k in streaming:
   id = k[1]     ----------> 1
   timestamp = k[2]  ------> 1652304692
   vsigns = k[3]    -------> Nested dictionary
```

This is how vsigns looks like

```
"vsigns":
    {
        "ECG":
        {
            "VPB_FREQ": "0",
            "STI": "+0.00"
        },
        "HR":
        {
            "HR_EKG": "87",
            "HR_PPG_1": "87",
            "HR_PULSED": "87"
        },
        "NIBP":
        {
            "NIBPS": "119",
            "NIBPD": "88",
            "NIBPM": "95"
        }
   }
```

And I want a json structure in the following format:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "ECG":
        {
           "timestamp": 1652304692,
            "VPB_FREQ": "0",
            "STI": "+0.00",
        }
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "HR":
        {
            "timestamp": 1652304692,
            "HR_EKG": "87",
            "HR_PPG_1": "87",
            "HR_PULSED": "87"
        }
        
},
{
    "id": "1",  
    "NIBP":
        {
            "timestamp": 1652304692,
            "NIBPS": "119",
            "NIBPD": "88",
            "NIBPM": "95"
        },
}]
```

I tried an approach but doesn't give me what I want. How do I get this right.

```
    for k in streaming:
       id = k[1]    
       timestamp = k[2]
       vsigns = k[3]
    vlist = []
    for k, v in vsigns.items():
       vdict = {"id": id,
                 k:{"timestamp":timestamp,
                     "vsigns": v}}
       vlist.append(vdict) 
print(vlist)
```

Output:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "ECG":
        {
            "timestamp": 1652951054.0,
            "vsigns":
            {
                "VPB_FREQ": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "HR":
        {
            "timestamp": 1652951054.0,
            "vsigns":
            {
                "HR_EKG": "126",
                "HR_PPG_1": "127",
                "HR_PULSED": "127"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "NIBP":
        {
            "timestamp": 1652951054.0,
            "vsigns":
            {
                "NIBPS": "95",
                "NIBPD": "46",
                "NIBPM": "62"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "doesn't give me what I want"?

Comment: Updated the post and I added the output I get for my code @ScottHunter

Comment: Your attempt *explicitly* adds an item (`vsigns`) that you don't want.  So don't do that.

Comment: It throws me syntax error when I do that

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong, but can't say much else w/o seeing what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code worked for me:

```
for k in streaming:
       id = k[1]    
       timestamp = k[2]
       vsigns = k[3]
    vlist = []
    for k, v in vsigns.items():
       v['timestamp'] = epoch_time
       vdict = {"id": id,
                k:v}
       vlist.append(vdict)
```